# Print multidimensional array data in html table using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array and trying  to print data in html table but only few data get printed in html table, array store values in  key value pair and again some array key contain its own array here i will print my array structure:

```
<?php 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['Item_details']);

?>

Array
(
    [Item] => 'item name'
    [Quantity] => 'quantity'
    [Size] => 'item size'
    [property 1] => Array
        (
            [property 1 key 1] => 'value 1'
            [property 1 key 2] =>'value 2'
            [property 1 key 3] => 'value 3'
            [property 1 key 4] => 'value 4'
        )


    [property 2] => Array
        (
            [property 2 key 1] => 'value 1'
            [property 2 key 2] => 'value 1'
        )

    [property 3] => Array
        (
            [property 3 key 1] => 'value 1'
        )

)
```

print data in table:

```
<?php 
     foreach ($_SESSION['Item_details'] as $key => $item_details) {
            if (is_array($item_details)) {
                echo '<tr>'.$key.'</tr>';

                foreach ($item_details as $name => $value) {
                    echo "<td>".$name.":". $value."<td>";
                }
            } else {
                 echo '<tr>'.$key.":". $item_details.'</tr>';

            }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: So what does it actually print?

Comment: @Jan Wichelmann  some values print in single line and some data in table

Comment: Please post the resulting HTML code, and the HTML code you are actually expecting.

Comment: Ok  I will post it now

Comment: @ Jan Wichelmann  actually i posted some dummy data due to some reason I can't post that live site output

Comment: Please mention how you'd like this data to be presented as a table, it's not aobvious...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not generating the correct HTML, for example `<td></td>` should be *inside* the `<tr>` but you have

```
foreach ($_SESSION['Item_details'] as $key => $item_details) {
  if (is_array($item_details)) {
    echo '<tr>'.$key.'</tr>';

    foreach ($item_details as $name => $value) {
      echo "<td>".$name.":". $value."<td>";
    }
```

Which will produce such HTML:

```html
<tr>Property 1</tr>
<td>property 1 key 1:value 1</td>
```

As you can see, `<td>` is not inside the `<tr>`

Which makes your browser to ignore some of those.